# HashMap implementation how do it faster and better in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have `HashMap` implementation, but operations are too slowly for me it must be faster, like normal hashmap. 
This is the code:

```
package Map;
public class HashMap<K, V> {

private Entry<K, V>[] table; // Array of Entry.
private int capacity = 4; // Initial capacity of HashMap

static class Entry<K, V> {
    K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K, V> next;

    public Entry(K key, V value, Entry<K, V> next) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public HashMap() {
    table = new Entry[capacity];
}

/**
 * Method allows you put key-value pair in HashMapCustom. If the map already
 * contains a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced. Note: method
 * does not allows you to put null key though it allows null values.
 * Implementation allows you to put custom objects as a key as well. Key
 * Features: implementation provides you with following features:- >provide
 * complete functionality how to override equals method. >provide complete
 * functionality how to override hashCode method.
 *
 * @param newKey
 * @param data
 */
public void put(K newKey, V data) {
    if (newKey == null)
        return; // does not allow to store null.

    // calculate hash of key.
    int hash = hash(newKey);
    // create new entry.
    Entry<K, V> newEntry = new Entry<K, V>(newKey, data, null);

    // if table location does not contain any entry, store entry there.
    if (table[hash] == null) {
        table[hash] = newEntry;
    } else {
        Entry<K, V> previous = null;
        Entry<K, V> current = table[hash];

        while (current != null) { // we have reached last entry of bucket.
            if (current.key.equals(newKey)) {
                if (previous == null) { // node has to be insert on first of
                                        // bucket.
                    newEntry.next = current.next;
                    table[hash] = newEntry;
                    return;
                } else {
                    newEntry.next = current.next;
                    previous.next = newEntry;
                    return;
                }
            }
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        previous.next = newEntry;
    }
}

/**
 * Method returns value corresponding to key.
 *
 * @param key
 */
public V get(K key) {
    int hash = hash(key);
    if (table[hash] == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        Entry<K, V> temp = table[hash];
        while (temp != null) {
            if (temp.key.equals(key))
                return temp.value;
            temp = temp.next; // return value corresponding to key.
        }
        return null; // returns null if key is not found.
    }
}

public boolean containsKey(K key) {
    int hash = hash(key);
    if (table[hash] == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        Entry<K, V> temp = table[hash];
        while (temp != null) {
            if (temp.key.equals(key))
                return true;
            temp = temp.next; // return value corresponding to key.
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Method removes key-value pair from HashMapCustom.
 *
 * @param key
 */
public boolean remove(K deleteKey) {

    int hash = hash(deleteKey);

    if (table[hash] == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        Entry<K, V> previous = null;
        Entry<K, V> current = table[hash];

        while (current != null) { // we have reached last entry node of
                                    // bucket.
            if (current.key.equals(deleteKey)) {
                if (previous == null) { // delete first entry node.
                    table[hash] = table[hash].next;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    previous.next = current.next;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 * Method displays all key-value pairs present in HashMapCustom., insertion
 * order is not guaranteed, for maintaining insertion order refer
 * LinkedHashMapCustom.
 *
 * @param key
 */
public void display() {

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        if (table[i] != null) {
            Entry<K, V> entry = table[i];
            while (entry != null) {
                System.out.print("{" + entry.key + "=" + entry.value + "}" + " ");
                entry = entry.next;
            }
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Method implements hashing functionality, which helps in finding the
 * appropriate bucket location to store our data. This is very important
 * method, as performance of HashMapCustom is very much dependent on this
 * method's implementation.
 *
 * @param key
 */
private int hash(K key) {
    return Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % capacity;
}

}
```

And when i try put big data, like:

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap();
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 200000000; i++){
map.put(i, "kotek"+i);
}
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```

It take too long time. I must implement it without another collections like: Set etc. I must put, remove, get and containsKey faster, like normal hashMap, but i don't know how implement that fast map.

Comment: You can find the implementation [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java).

Comment: I think a good idea would be to *prepend* the `Entry` in case of hash collision, intead of adding it at the end.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you cannot prepend the entry, since you must make sure you dont have the same key already. For that - you must check every entry in the bucket

Comment: @paranoidAndroid: that's not per se a problem since when you do a lookup, you will never get to that duplicate key. You can remove duplicates occasionally.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You mean keep all duplicates and just return the newest one upon `get()` ? Yeah, it should work.

Comment: @paranoidAndroid: indeed and ocassionally, for instance in the event of rehashing, remove the duplicates such that in the end there is not that much overhead when a lookup is done.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your map is slow is because you have many collisions. Your capacity is 4 and you never expand it. So effectively the `put()` operation becomes approximately O(N) after the 4 first `put()` calls. Also as William mentioned, you add your new entries on the end of the bucket. So changing that to adding as the first element will boost the performance . But still it's not a good practice to keep your map in constant size of 4 - since your `put()` will be fine but `get()` will still be O(N)

EDIT
You cannot prepend the entry. Since you must go over all the entries on the bucket to make sure you dont already have an *equal* key